# Tooltip in a image map (on mousehover)

Tags: css, tooltip

I have this tooltip code that run's a tooltip when i mousehover the entire image. But I want to do the same process but with several imagemap inside an image.

Any ideas?

thank you.

```css
a.tooltip {outline:none; }
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:10px; margin-left:28px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:absolute; color:#111;
    border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;}
.callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;top:30px;border:0;left:-12px;}
    
/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    <img src="http://www.invasao.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/google.jpg" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="poly" coords="22,46" href="#" />
    </map>
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/cssttp/callout.gif" />
        <img src="/tooltip/src/tooltips-cd2.jpg" style="float:right;" />
        <strong>CSS only Tooltip</strong><br />
        Pure CSS popup tooltips with clean semantic XHTML.
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? different tooltips for different parts of image?

Comment: Yes @PrakharSingh, different tooltip for different parts of the same image.

Comment: What kind of image-maps? complex png images or shapes?

Comment: It's a png of a stadium and i want to use a "poly" shape in different areas of the image